# CV not listed on Google

Tags: support, status-bydesign, jobs, google

I have done a search on Google using:

```
site:careers.stackoverflow.com
```

And I don't see my CV listed. Why? Surely Google has indexed my SO questions, which link to my SO profile, which links to my career CV.

Comment: When did you link to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over a certain threshold, [the `nofollow` on your profile website link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stack-overflow/7238#7238) is removed.

`nofollow` means that search engines will not "follow" the link, and therefore it will not be indexed from that particular location. Now, if it is linked from somewhere else, it would probably be indexed.

However, any and all links inside the [About section are still nofollowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6905/can-we-not-relnofollow-links-in-profile-about-me-for-users-with-3000-rep/11358#11358). Which means if you want to try and link to your CV from there, it won't do much searchbot good.

Either link to your CV from your own site (you're not currently doing so) or crack 2000 reputation on Stack Overflow and drop the link in your website field.

Answer (score 1):

Bottom line:

Your CV is only available if it's linked to on the internet.

Stack Overflow puts `rel='nofollow'` in all links in a profile page; unless you have 2000 reputation, and then your `Website` link is able to be spidered.

Choices:

1. Link to CV through personal blog or Linked In.
2. Get 2000+ reputation and put it in your `website` field.