# How can I get "dofollow" link in my Stack Overflow Profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, hyperlinks, nofollow

By default, all links in SO profiles have `rel="nofollow"` set. But I have checked some profiles like [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) & [Anoop Vaidya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1395941/anoop-vaidya), and they have `dofollow` (i.e., not `nofollow`) links to their websites.

Like you see [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) has a `dofollow` link to *C# in Depth* and [Anoop Vaidya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1395941/anoop-vaidya) has a `dofollow` link to *Interview Questions on Cocoa*.

So, I want to know how can I get a `dofollow` link to my website in my SO Profile?

I know 2000 reputation is required to get dofollow link in Website field. but what is the condition to get dofollow link in About Me Section. **Ex.** Jon Skeet got on C# in Depth.

one more thing If I have 2k+ reputation in Stack Overflow so its possible that I get `dofollow` links in Pro Webmasters?

Comment: Just use markdown as you normally would for posts. Your "About Me" section is entirely editable.

Comment: @SumitBijvani: The link you're referring to Jon Skeet's About Me is `Author of <a href="http://www.manning.com/affiliate/idevaffiliate.php?id=876_230" rel="nofollow">C# in Depth</a>.<br>`. It's explicitly `nofollow`, *not* `dofollow`.

Comment: SO gives nofollow links you can check all links have attribute `rel="nofollow"`

Comment: @SumitBijvani Then just use the html tags.

Comment: Ah, but you're referring to the second link, the one in the list: `<a href="http://csharpindepth.com">C# in Depth</a>`. He probably created that using the raw HTML tags.

Comment: @DavidRobinson its dofollow `<a href="http://csharpindepth.com">C# in Depth</a>` check 2nd link not first

Comment: @DavidRobinson how can I do this?

Comment: @SumitBijvani: You can use HTML (instead of Markdown) in posts/About Me.

Comment: @DavidRobinson no it doesn't work

Comment: @SumitBijvani: Interesting- you are right!

Comment: @SumitBijvani: Works for me.

Comment: @RocketHazmat can you show me that link?

Comment: @SumitBijvani: I edited my "About Me" on Stack Overflow, added `<a href="http://example.com">My Link</a>`, and it worked.  What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What happened when you tried?

Comment: @RocketHazmat when I use `<a href>` it will automatically add `rel="nofollow"` in link

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Check the source- it will have `rel="nofollow"` added

Comment: @DavidRobinson: Nope!  It doesn't!

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Where is the example link on your profile? (I'm looking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat))

Comment: @RocketHazmat you got dofollow link. I have checked your profile `<a class="url" rel="me" href="http://Labs.NTICompassInc.com">`.  but how?

Comment: @DavidRobinson: http://stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat

Comment: @RocketHazmat: That source says `<a href="http://example.com" rel="nofollow">My Link</a></p>`.

Comment: @DavidRobinson look he got dofollow in his bio section on his website

Comment: @SumitBijvani: **That's** what you are referring to?!  That has *nothing* to do with *ANY* link in the "About Me" block!

Comment: @RocketHazmat you can check my profile `http://stackoverflow.com/users/1087998/sumit-bijvani` I have added links but all are nofollow

Comment: @RocketHazmat I am referring to whole profile. not only about me block

Comment: @DavidRobinson: It totally didn't have the `rel="nofollow"` when I first tested it.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Uh huh ;-). Anyway, it does now, and it does on mine.

Comment: how its possible that @RocketHazmat got dofollow links and I am not?

Comment: @SumitBijvani: 'Cuz I'm awesome! :)

Comment: @SumitBijvani: He no longer has any dofollow links in his profile. (Do you still see any?)

Comment: @DavidRobinson: I tested it and it seemed like my links didn't have the `rel="nofollow"`, but I looked again, and they do, so I removed the link.

Comment: @DavidRobinson yes, he has... check his website link beside his profile image. it has dofollow link

Comment: @SumitBijvani: Oh, that one? Mine is dofollow for that link too. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/712603/david-robinson?tab=activity).

Comment: IIRC `rel="nofollow"` get removed at a certain reputation threshold. There was a question about this at some point in time…

Comment: @SumitBijvani: That link is *always* `dofollow`,  just set your "webpage" in your profile.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: False, he has his website set and it's `nofollow`. Like minitech said, it looks like it's a rep threshold thing.

Comment: @RocketHazmat i have set my webpage but it is still nofollow

Comment: @minitech how much reputation for dofollow link?

Comment: @DavidRobinson: I stand corrected.  I didn't know :)

Comment: @SumitBijvani: Sorry, I made a mistake. The reputation threshold is 2,000, and it’s only for the “official” website link. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51156/160410

Comment: @minitech 2000 or 3000?? because there is answer on my post it show 3000 reputation required

Comment: @SumitBijvani - What's the point behind [that edit (No. 9)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/171503/revisions)?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to earn 2000 points for the `rel="nofollow"` restriction for your website link to be lifted.

Note that links in your "About me" section will always have the `rel="nofollow"` restriction applied *except for the link in your `Website` field*. It has to be an exact match though, if one has a trailing slash and the other doesn't then the restriction is applied anyway.

To rephrase that: If you enter a link in your `Website` profile field, *and* use that exact same link in your About Me section, then that link is not given the `nofollow` restriction.

Jon Skeet lists `http://csharpindepth.com/` as his `Website` link, so the exact same link in the About Me section is not given the `nofollow` restriction. All *other* links in that section do.

The limitation is *per site*; if you have multiple, associated accounts across the Stack Exchange network, the restriction is not lifted for accounts with less than 2k even if other accounts have reached 2k already. Jon Skeet's [Code Review account](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/16031/jon-skeet) is well below 2k and has the `nofollow` restriction applied to his links.

Comment: but some accounts also get dofollow in About Me section like Jon Skeet

Comment: @MartijnPieters Jon Skeet get the dofollow link you can check his 2nd link

Comment: I have added same link twice but getting nofollow in both

Comment: so how can I get dofollow in my About Me section?

Comment: Check my profile I also have added link twice but didn't get dofollow on any link http://stackoverflow.com/users/1087998/sumit-bijvani

Comment: I think its not because I have updated my profile last year and I still didn't get any dofollow link

Comment: @SumitBijvani You don't have enough reputation to have the `nofollow` removed, yet.

Comment: @AndrewBarber yah, I don't have as per Martijn answer I have to get 3000 reputation for it

Comment: @SumitBijvani: Hey, here was me assuming you had at least 3k points. The *first* part of my answer stated you needed at least 3k, so you are not even eligible. Thanks Andrew, for pointing that out.

Comment: @MartijnPieters means I have to get 3k reputation so I will get dofollow in About me section?

Comment: @MartijnPieters you have awesome profile and you get nofollow in About me section

Comment: I think only Jon skeet have rights to get dofollow link in about me section :D

Comment: that also right :)

Comment: thanks for your help :) and +1 for your answer. thank you very much

Comment: Great!! Eric Lippert also have dofollow in his about me section

Comment: It means that 200k reputation required for getting dofollow link on about me section?

Comment: I think not check this profile http://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell he also have 200k+ reputation and he got 1 dofollow link in about me section

Comment: @SumitBijvani: [Pekka (191k)](http://stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka) has nofollow while [S. Lott (171k)](http://stackoverflow.com/users/10661/s-lott) does not. I think Martijn Pieters is correct.

Comment: haha!! lots of confusions

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong: S. Lott's blog isn't nofollowed, but all his other links are. I suspect there's a whitelist at play.

Comment: @mmyers: Solved it. I had a `/` at the end of my own Webpage field. I updated  my About Me section to include the slash, and now my `nofollow` restriction is gone too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you got dofollow. you have just recently update your profile and you got dofollow link in about me section

Comment: @SumitBijvani: That is what I am saying. I found the problem with my About Me section, my personal site was listed *without* a trailing slash while my Website section had it *with* the slash. The `nofollow` is removed automatically when the two match.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I also tried but didn't got dofollow link

Comment: @SumitBijvani: That is because you do not yet have 3000 points! You need to have at least 3k before *any* nofollow is removed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters okay thanks. let me get 3k reputations

Comment: @SumitBijvani: I did some more investigating and it is indeed 2k now; the limit has been lowered (I don't know when), but I just confirmed that people with 2k already have the nofollow removed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's very good and important news for me.

Comment: FYI: It's been 2K for *years*. I don't know if it was ever 3k.

Comment: @Shog9: I think [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6905) threw me off. Rereading it now I see that the threshold was 2k then too and 3k was a *proposed* threshold for the feature req.

Comment: @SumitBijvani: Why the need for a bounty? I explained this already. The link you enter in the `Website` field of your profile *and* in your About Me section is exempt from the nofollow restriction (provided you have 2k reputation or more). Jon Skeet lists the C# book link in his Website field *and* in the About Me section.

Comment: I contact 2 person who have 2k+ reputation but they also don't get dofollow link in About me section that's why I started bounty. your answer is fine but I am confuse in About me section

Comment: @SumitBijvani: The link *must* match *exactly* to what was entered in the `Website` field.

Comment: Yah it is matching. I have tried 3 times in both accounts :(

Comment: @SumitBijvani: Please link to the accounts then, so we can verify that they did it correct?

Comment: @MartijnPieters you also got the dofollow link. can you please add other link in your about me section

Comment: @SumitBijvani: I *already* tested this exhaustively. All links in my profile *except the one I named in my `Website` section* have `nofollow`.

Comment: ok let me check again tomorrow in my friend's account.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so, 2k reputation is enough to get dofollow link in about me section?

Comment: @SumitBijvani: Yes, *provided that link is the same as what you put in the `Website` field*.

Comment: @SumitBijvani: Here are some more examples of 2k+ users whose About Me section contains the same link as the `Website` field: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1380680/reinier-torenbeek, http://stackoverflow.com/users/351901/bruno077, http://stackoverflow.com/users/285850/olivier-croisier, http://stackoverflow.com/users/496992/patrick-boos

Comment: okay thank for sample profiles

Comment: one more thing If I have 2k+ reputation in Stack Overflow so its possible that I get dofollow links in Pro Webmasters?

Comment: @SumitBijvani: No, the restriction is *per site*.

Comment: I think my profile is an anomaly on Seasoned Advice! http://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/52528/caleb?tab=profile. The link in the about me section is nofollow, but my website like is not nofollow. I made sure the URLs are identical. I have ~2100 rep, here's a profile with ~2600 rep: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/8457/tobias-op-den-brouw

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @Caleb: without moderator-level access to your account, I can't tell why, but a strict string comparison between the two links is not equal. I know they *render* the same, but perhaps there is a space or other hard-to-spot character somewhere?

Comment: Interesting. How did you do the strict string comparison to see they are not equal? I tried copying the string from the website field into the About Me section with no luck.

Comment: @Caleb: I can't *see* they are not equal; I just know that that is how the property is tested for.

Comment: I've tried many different variations to no avail. I tried pasting both strings from source into a string checker and there is no difference. Perhaps there is a 2.5k reputation threshold for About Me nofollow removal in SA.

Answer (score 10):

After some testing, I came up with the following conclusions:

- If you have over 2000 reputation, your website link won't have `nofollow`.
- If that same link is there on your about page, it won't get `nofollow` either.
- Any other links *will* have `nofollow`.

There's nothing much to do about it, it's just the way it is.