# What does it mean when an answer is submitted by Community?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, community-user

What does it mean when an answer is submitted by Community? (The [example](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/67332/14897) I came across - the screenshot is from the Aviation home page.)

[image]

Surely a user didn't answer and delete the unregistered account right away (it takes 24 hours to delete, right?). Is it an answer submitted through the "Contact Us" page?

As far as I can tell, it's not addressed here: [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738/392799)

What would be the use cases?

Comment: Fingers crossed SE is not rolling out a Community ♦ AI answerer. Wait... we would have been training it all along. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Surely a user didn't answer and delete the unregistered account right away

I think they did (an Aviation mod needs to confirm); because accounts with very limited activity will be deleted right away, according to the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/295232):

> If you have never posted or voted more than once on your profile, your account will be immediately deleted.

That's a bit ambiguous, but the ["more than once" bit also pertains to posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309829/295232).

Comment: can confirm. deleted 26 seconds after answering