# Help center page for deleting accounts still lists old criteria for deleting the account immediately without a 24-hour wait

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, deleted-accounts

For a long time, there's been [a feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309829/should-we-disallow-users-from-immediately-deleting-their-accounts-if-theyve-mad?noredirect=1) where users who've contributed very little activity on the site, who later request deletion of their account, have their account deleted immediately upon requesting it rather than having to wait 24 hours before their account is deleted.

As I state in the above link, the previous criteria for users to be eligible for immediate deletion were that they've never posted or voted *more* than once. The criteria were, however, [changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/352669/377214) in August 2020 to having to have *never* posted on the site before and having less than 101* (actually [101 or less](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/7979/78)) reputation.

However, the [help center page on deleting accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account) still mentions the old, no longer correct criteria:

> If you have never posted or voted more than once on your profile, it will be *immediately* deleted.

Can this page please be changed to reflect the current criteria? It should read like this:

> If you have never made any posts and you have 101 or less reputation, it will be *immediately* deleted.

(To clarify, votes [are no longer considered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314617/prevent-users-from-immediately-deleting-their-accounts-if-theyve-made-one-post#comment1178928_352669) by the new criteria. Also, a community member [did some testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/7979/78) and found that accounts with *exactly* 101 reputation are also immediately deleted if they've never posted.)

Comment: @V2Blast Do note that there's an [active feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361583/377214) asking for another change to be made to the criteria, i.e. that votes should continue to be considered.

Comment: I'll leave it to the mods to decide whether that post should have the [status-review] tag added; for now, I'm just editing the help center page to match the current behavior.

Comment: @V2Blast Wasn't asking for a tag there; wanted to make sure it was on staff's internal radar to implement even if it doesn't have the tag added.

Comment: Having some posts get on "staff's internal radar" despite not being tagged would somewhat defeat the purpose of the status-review tag, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Rob That's how things worked before the whole [tag:status-review] escalation system was [introduced in March 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344586/our-commitment-to-responding-to-meta-and-moderators).

Comment: @SonictheAnti-NewVariant-hog, so not how it works now then?  (no need to answer, the question's rhetorical)

Comment: @Rob Not every request filed since the escalation process was introduced that was subsequently completed had to go through that route. Quite a few still went through the traditional routes that existed long before that new route was introduced. (I began writing this comment before you edited it to say it was rhetorical, and comment edits aren't loaded immediately.)

Answer (score 3):

I've updated the `/help/deleting-account` page to reflect the current criteria for immediate self-deletion of a user profile. (I've also replaced the screenshots with new ones matching the current look of the profile pages, and done some minor copyediting.)

Thanks for pointing this out!