# Is it intentional that profile website links aren't nofollowed?

Tags: support, bug, profile-page

Pretty much exactly as the title says, the website link you can put into your profile isn't `rel='nofollow'`ed.

Is this intentional, or should this be fixed?

Comment: [`rel="nofollow"` is removed for 2k+ rep users according to Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11358/215013)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is intentional.

Without nofollow the search engines will give a higher ranking to that page since a high ranked page, like any site in the SE network links it (called backlinks).

If SE would allow the use of backlinks, the profile page can be used for search engine spamming, which is not what we all want.

Only users with 2K reputation or more are deemed trustworthy enough to [have the nofollow removed on their profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11358/245360).